How to not refresh the entire state of listview builder
My goal is to retrive data progressively and not all at once. For that purpose I'm using a ListView builder that, when it reaches the bottom of the current List try to Add other elements asking to DB.
The problem is that when I get the response from the DB, the ListView builder entirely refreshes the list. This involves also all the previous cards and this causes a very bad looking refresh of the entire page.
I don't like this to happen.
I'll provide the important pieces of code. in the build() I just call the buildCardsView
Widget buildCardsView() { 
   return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cards.length + (_isLastPage ? 0 : 1),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

          if (index == _cards.length - _nextPageTrigger && !_isLastPage) {
            fetchData();
          }

          final WalletWatch card = _cards[index];
          return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: CustomBottomBigCard(
                  watchID: watch.watchId,
                  screenWidth: widget.width,
                  walletWatch: watch,
                  imgUrl: getDownloadURL(watch.imageuri),
              );
          )
    );
  }

The state of the Widget ...
class _CardWalletScreenState extends State<CardWalletScreen> {
  late double _width;
  late bool _isLastPage;
  late int _pageNumber;
  late bool _error;
  late bool _loading;
  final int _numberOfPostsPerRequest = 10;
  late List<WalletWatch> _cards;
  final int _nextPageTrigger = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _width = SizeConfig.screenW!;
    _pageNumber = 0;
    _cards = [];
    _isLastPage = false;
    _loading = true;
    _error = false;
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    var req =
        await getUserWalletWatches(12, _pageNumber, _numberOfPostsPerRequest);
    setState(() {
      for (var walletWatch in req) {
        _cards.add(walletWatch);
      }
     _isLastPage = req.length < _numberOfPostsPerRequest;
     _loading = false;
     _pageNumber = _pageNumber + 1;
    });
  }

Do you know how to simply Add the new retrived data ad the end of the previous ones?
(The code of the CustomBottomBigCard is down below)
class CustomBottomBigCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomBottomBigCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.watchID,
    required this.screenWidth,
    required this.walletWatch,
    required this.imgUrl,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int watchID;
  final double screenWidth;
  final WalletWatch walletWatch;
  final Future<String> imgUrl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(WatchScreen.id, arguments: Watch(
          watchId: walletWatch.watchId,
          condition: walletWatch.condition,
          numberOfShares: walletWatch.numberOfShares,
          retailPrice: walletWatch.retailPrice,
          initialPrice: walletWatch.initialPrice,
          actualPrice: walletWatch.actualPrice,
          dialcolor: walletWatch.dialcolor,
          year: walletWatch.year,
          imageuri: walletWatch.imageuri,
          description: walletWatch.description,
          modelTypeId: walletWatch.modelTypeId,
          modelType: walletWatch.modelType,
        ));
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black26,
            width: 1,
          ),
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              blurRadius: 2,
              offset: Offset(3, 3), // Shadow position
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: screenWidth * 0.04),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: imgUrl,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
                          child: Image.network(
                            snapshot.data!,
                            width: screenWidth * 0.3,
                            height: screenWidth * 0.3,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      } else {
                        return const Text('Image not found');
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: screenWidth * 0.05),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
                      color: (walletWatch.increaseRate >= 0)
                          ? Colors.lightGreen
                          : Colors.red,
                    ),
                    child: Text('${walletWatch.increaseRate}%'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  walletWatch.modelType.model.brandname,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black38,
                    height: 1,
                    fontSize: screenWidth * 0.05,
                    fontFamily: 'Bebas',
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  walletWatch.modelType.model.modelname,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    height: 1,
                    fontSize: screenWidth * 0.055,
                    fontFamily: 'Bebas',
                  ),
                ),
                Text('Reference: ${walletWatch.modelType.reference}'),
                Text(
                    'Retail Price: ${formatAmountFromDouble(walletWatch.retailPrice)}€'),
                SizedBox(height: screenWidth * 0.02),
                Text(
                    'Owned Shares: ${walletWatch.owned}/${walletWatch.numberOfShares}'),
                Text(
                    'Initial Price: ${formatAmountFromDouble(walletWatch.initialPrice)}€'),
                Text(
                    'Actual Price: ${formatAmountFromDouble(walletWatch.actualPrice)}€'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Instead of calling fetchData() inside itemBuilder of ListView just use ScrollController.
class LazyLoadingListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LazyLoadingListView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LazyLoadingListView> createState() => _LazyLoadingListViewState();
}

class _LazyLoadingListViewState extends State<LazyLoadingListView> {
  // List<int> items = List.generate(20, (index) => index);
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _loading = false;

  late double _width;
  late bool _isLastPage;
  late int _pageNumber;
  late bool _error;
  // late bool _loading;
  final int _numberOfPostsPerRequest = 10;
  late List<WalletWatch> _cards;
  final int _nextPageTrigger = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        fetchData();
      }
    });
    _pageNumber = 0;
    _isLastPage = false;
    _cards = [];

    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List<WalletWatch>> getUserWalletWatches(
      int i, pageNumber, numberOfPostsPerRequest) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    final list =
        List.generate(20, (index) => WalletWatch(id: _cards.length + index));

    return list;
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    if (!_loading) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = true;
      });

      var req =
          await getUserWalletWatches(12, _pageNumber, _numberOfPostsPerRequest);

      setState(() {
        // _cards.addAll(req);
        for (var walletWatch in req) {
          _cards.add(walletWatch);
        }
        _isLastPage = req.length < _numberOfPostsPerRequest;
        _pageNumber = _pageNumber + 1;
        _loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Lazy Loading ListView'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: _cards.length +
                    1, // Add one more item for the loading indicator
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == _cards.length) {
                    return _buildLoadingIndicator();
                  }
                  return CustomBottomBigCard(walletWatch: _cards[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoadingIndicator() {
    return const Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomBottomBigCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomBottomBigCard({super.key, required this.walletWatch});

  final WalletWatch walletWatch;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
        child: Center(child: Text(walletWatch.id.toString())),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here's the result. result_video
Here's the result with your CustomBottomBigCard. updated_custom_item

Actually it doesn't work :( - In the itemBuilder, when index == items.lenght, there is the loading indicator, but it never ends. No data is retrived from the DB.

I guess, If you are getting data from db successfully then there's a problem with your code where you are adding the new data into the list. So, can you tell me the type of "req" when you are fetching data. Is it List or something else?

Yep ... it is a Future<List>

Updated the fetchData() try it and it is also working with for loop like your code but I am not getting data from any db. just waiting for 2 seconds then create a list then adding in card list. and it's working

And try to print the result of getUserWalletWatches() also

The result got from the API is this one: Future<List>

have you tried the updated code of fetchData() ?

Yep. I've tried. The problem is that the fetchData is never reached :) The method _scrollContreller.addListeners() never ends. The problem is not in the if condition btw ... because I've put an else to check and the code never reaches that part ...

You should just run the code from the answer because it's a working code even in my live apps. So, you should try to run this answer in a separate class and check how it works

Your code is good and it works perfectly with some data (for example strings), but when I try to Build a Little more complex stateless widgets (like a small cards), when the new cards are addded the entire List refreshes

How you find that the entire list refreshing? It'll be good if you upload a short video and updated code in your question.

I have updated the answer and added a custom widget (CustomBottomBigCard)  in list view and also added a screen recording. Give it a try

Mmm your CustomBigCard isn't really like mine. I added the code of my Card (have a look about it), but unfortunately I don't have the video because since your solution wasn't worked I didn't use it.

Btw as I said ... the entire List refresh. Not all the page on my screen ... just the portion that contains the List of cards. Apart from that it works brilliantly :)

Why are you using Future imgUrl; in your CustomBottomBigCard().  There's no need to do that. Like you already got the data inside listview.builder So you can directly use it. Then, you can directly show an image without using FutureBuilder. Using cached_network_image package will be a better option

Btw I asked for video of your running app where the list is refreshing. NOT my code.

And I have added another video recording with your CustomBottomBigCard(). And I think the list is not refreshing when new items are adding to list. Also before running it, I changed your Future imgUrl to String url .

Probably I've written something badly because I need imgUrl to be a Future. I've updated the code so you can see I retrieve the url with a method  (that uses Firebase) that returns a Future. Do you think I should have done differently? If yes, where (and when) do you Believe I need to retrieve the images?
P.S. Your List works perfectly but you're getting just an image. I need the specific one for each watch. (Thanks for you support. I really appreciate)

It will be a good thing. If you upload a video of your working code. Like where's the list is refershing.
